# Join different table columns into one using Azure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I need your help in the below scenario in Azure SQL. I would like to join 3 tables data into 1 table with getting columns value as shown below,

[image]

Hope you could help me with writing sql query. Looking forward to it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help (just replace with your actual tablename and columnname). Simply you need to left join which give the null result from Table B and Table C, if there is no record related of Table A

```
Select 
    ta.locaiton, ta.date , ta.Table_A_Count, tb.Table_A_Count, tc.Table_A_Count
From tableA ta
    Left Join tablB tb on ta.Location = tb.Location and ta.Date = tb.Date 
    Left Join tablC tc on ta.Location = tc.Location and ta.Date = tc.Date
```